# Looping through rest of videos after random page load

Tags: javascript, php, video

I have 3 videos that I would like to be shown on my webpage.  The problem is I want a random video to load but after that I need to show the other 2 videos.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  This is what I have below...

```
<div class="banner-vid">
    <video class="videoBG desk" preload="auto" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" poster="" style="width: 1600px; height: auto; top: -64px; left: 0px;">
        <?php $array = array('vid1.mp4','vid2.mp4','vid3.mp4'); 
         $shuffle = shuffle($array);
    ?>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php foreach ($array as $vids) { echo "$vids "; } ?>">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt see this.  I apologize.  I am not against using js, but would rather try to stick with php.

Comment: May be you should store video names in session, than check is played or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shuffle function.

```
shuffle($array);
```

It will randomize the order in your array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Yes but would this show the remaining 2 videos and for instance not play video 1 twice?

Comment: Do you mean like a playlist ?

Comment: So the idea is you have a random video start on page load.  Next the other 2 play.  That is it.  No repeating videos after the first video is loaded.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It sounds like you want a video playlist. There are many that you can use, here is an example : http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/playlist.html

Comment: Not quite what Im looking for. I am using these random videos for a bg video.  I like the the shuffle() function you came up with but based on what  php.net said my code doesnt work.  See updated code.  The problem is it uses all three videos and doesnt want to interate through them in the foreach.

Comment: You need to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to have one single video player displayed in your page, with this behavior : play video1, after video1 is finished, play video2, after video2 is finished, play video3 ? Or is it something else ?

Comment: No video player....Lets say for this case I am trying to load the videos from a videos folder.  I am trying to randomize the first video.  So it could be vid2.mp4 on one page load.  The next time it could be vid1.mp4.  The videos are random on page load.  After, lets say vid1.mp4 is the video loaded it should play vid2.mp4, and vid3.mp4 next and then no other video will play.  The next time on a page load it could be vid3.mp4 that loads first.  After that vid1,mp4 and vid2.mp4 will play in sequence.  Is that a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to alfallouji's answer, I think using `shuffle()` is not the perfect solution.

I can't think of a native function that directly removes one element and prepends it again, so this is a quick implementation of your desired logic:

```
<?php
$videos = array('vid1.mp4', 'vid2.mp4', 'vid3.mp4');

$firstVideoKey = mt_rand(0,count($videos)-1); // pick random index
$firstVideo = $videos[$firstVideoKey];        // get video at index
unset($videos[$firstVideoKey]);               // unset array value at index
array_unshift($videos, $firstVideo);          // prepend video

foreach ($videos as $video) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful explanation, I'll really have something to pick from this one.